# Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'triangle 45'

Tags: tikz-pgf

now I've an issues on tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


now I've an issues on tikz.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\clip(-4.263907326357041,-2.169808170515719) rectangle (4.512244003818671,1.5716037123486593);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-3,1)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-3,-1)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (3,0);
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (-3,1) -- (-1.47,0.49);
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (-3,-1) -- (-1.548,-0.516);
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (-2.076774358733703,1.5254134421898398) node[anchor=north west] {$X$};
\draw (-2.253451692101613,-0.8880281736084783) node[anchor=north west] {$Y$};
\draw (0.5629759052396007,-0.1110413040590908059) node[anchor=north west] {$S = X + Y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: why can you not post a document that shows the problem?

Comment: I use Overleaf, can I put the link of the project ?

Comment: no make a small but complete example here

Comment: I don"t understand what you wanna say

Comment: I did it for you this time. Simply delete `,>=triangle 45` and the error will go

Comment: @Fractal Please add a minimal (non)working example so we check if you load all the libraries necessary to use this special arrow tip. (do this by adding the code to your question. Not as link to overleaf and not as your 7th non-answer)

Comment: You need to load the deprecated `arrows` library for the `triangle 45` arrow tip.

Answer (score 2):

You have not said what output you want, you can delete

```
,>=triangle 45
```

and use default arrows, or add

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

to your preamble, to define this form.